# Can a kingdom be destabilized by an influx of enemy gold?

Tags: world-building, economy

A few years ago I read a role-playing game supplement that described a cold war between kingdom Good and kingdom Bad. Both kingdoms used metal coins with silver as the most common followed by gold. Kingdom Bad planned to flood kingdom Good with gold coins, disrupting Good's economy in preparation for Bad's invasion. So far as I remember, Bad planned to use *real* gold coins and not counterfeit ones.

To me it seems that all Bad is doing is emptying its coffers to fill Good's, essentially paying for Good's defenses, weapons, and mercenaries.

However, I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing. Is this, in fact, really a reasonable plot? Can this style of economic warfare somehow destroy kingdom Good?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for [Worldbuilding stack exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).  That doens't make it a bad question (it isn't), just one where that stack will be a better fit.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I think this question can be answered if the question named the product (and the question's tags were edited to include the corresponding system). That is, if the game system contains enough information about its setting's economics (and magic!), a reasonable answer can be crafted that explains why or why not this plot may succeed. However, without more information — that is, if the question remains *Could this plot work in any RPG setting?* — this question is too broad. Thank you for participating, though, and happy holidays!

Comment: it was a Swedish game, Eon. The serting is low fantasy, low magic.

Comment: This [*Eon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_(role-playing_game))? That's cool. Do you remember which supplement?

Comment: First edition core.

Comment: Are you asking whether it can be made to work in the economic rules (if any) of a particular game, or are you asking if it would work in real economic terms? Readers here tend to view questions like this as the former once a game is specified, and that tends to be unrelated to how real historical economics works, so it’s important to be clear on what your intended question is.

Comment: Eon prided itself on high realism, so Yes, I am asking if this would work in the real world.

Comment: @Obak: Then, as Korvin said, it's considered off-topic for this site, and would be more suited to worldbuilding.SE.